# SSIS package won't save SQL command

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am updating an SSIS package and modifying the SQL command of a lookup transformation, but have found that the command won't save. I will update the command, close the editor, save the package, close and re-open Visual Studio (Professional 2015), but my changes are not preserved. There is a config file (.dtsConfig) for the package in which I have made the changes as well, but still no dice. Changes to the project, such as variables and connection managers and their use within the package (save for the SQL command) are, however, maintained.

What reasons might there be for why this package won't let me save updated SQL commands?

Comment: <Wild Guess> By any chance does the SQL for this command come from a variable, where the variable is defined by an expression and not a static value?  If yes, the expression will recalculate when the project opens.

Comment: No; a variable is used as parameter but the command itself is not a variable.

Comment: I think @JimHorn is right - you might have an 'EvaluateAsExpression' set somewhere higher up that sets the query from an expression.

Comment: I changed it in properties, expand expressions and you will see the sql you want to edit. edit the sql, evaluate expression and click ok. now the sql will take the changes. I also was changing by editing the task, and it kept changing the edited sql.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure of why this situation was occurring, but opening the lookup in the advanced editor and modifying the SqlCommand and SqlCommandParam fields allowed preservation of my changes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saving the package, be certain to also run a build.  This recreates the .dtsx package file with the new changes.  Your question did not mention having done this very important step.

Comment: This just spits the dtsx file into the bin folder - if the dtsx is not being edited from the bin it'll make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't answering the question, but provides you a guideline on how to troubleshoot the problem:

After the change do a right click on a package and view a code in XML. Look for your "SQL statement" is it there?

Copy/paste XML into separate file, save and close the solution. Reopen it and see if code has changed. Compare the changes.